# Why is mysql_num_rows returning zero?

Tags: mysql, c

I am using C MySQL API

```
int numr=mysql_num_rows(res);
```

It always returns zero, but in my table there are 4 rows are there. However, I am getting the correct fields count.

what is the problem? Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: Is "mysql_num_rows" a PHP thing?  It is definitely not in any C runtime out there.  If it is the PHP function you should include that info.

Comment: post the code which came before this, which created the result.

Comment: Can you please show the code in its entirety? The problem isn't on the line displayed.

Comment: @Ed, it's in the C API (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-num-rows.html)

Comment: @Ed, This has nothing to do with PHP. There's a C function call called mysql_num_rows() as part of the mysql client library. The PHP function is based on that C function, but in this case that's totally irrelevant. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-num-rows.html

Comment: @Paul, probably more flattering to me than you, but we seem to think alike these days. :)

Comment: Look at the first edition of this thread, not the current edited version.  I have never used MySQL and searching for that method name brought up PHP tutorials.  Look at the first post...

Comment: Please show the code that assigns the res variable.

Comment: friends i got the number of rows from MYSQL_RES
instead of using mysql_use_result() i used mysql_store_result()
then i got the correct number of rows values

thanks for ur replies

Answer (score 5):

Just a guess:

> If you use `mysql_use_result()`, `mysql_num_rows()` does not return the correct value until all the rows in the result set have been retrieved.

(from the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-num-rows.html))

Comment: If you need the number of rows before calling mysql_fetch_row(), use mysql_store_result() instead of mysql_use_result().

Answer (score 2):

The only reason to receive a zero from `mysql_num_rows(<variable_name>)` is because the query did not return anything.

You haven't posted the query here that you run and then assign the result to your **res** variable so we can't check it.

But try running that exact query in your DB locally through whatever DB management software you use and see if you are able to achieve any results.

If the query is working fine, then it must be the way you're running the query in C, otherwise your query is broken.

Maybe post up a bit more of your code from C where you make the query and then run it.

Thanks

Comment: Upvoted. It sounds like his query has a where clause which is not matching anything or is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count the number of rows in a table, say

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name
```

You will get back a single column in a single row containing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I too have this problem.  But I noticed that mysql.h defines mysql_num_rows() to return a "my_ulonglong".  Also in the header file you will see that there is a type def for my_ulonglong.  On my system size of a my_ulonglong is 8 bytes.  When we try to print this out or cast this to an int we probably get the first four bytes which are zero.  However I printed out the eight bytes at the address of my_ulonglong variable and it prints all zeros.  So I think this function just doesn't work.

```
`my_ulonglong numOfRows;
MYSQL *resource;
MYSQL *connection;

mysql_query(connection,"SELECT * FROM channels");
resource = mysql_use_result(connection);
numChannels = mysql_num_rows(resource);
printf("Writing numChannels: %lu\n", numChannels);  // returns 0
printf("Size of numChannels is %d.\n", sizeof(numChannels)); // returns 8

// however
unsigned char * tempChar;
tempChar = (unsigned char *) &numChannels;
for (i=0; i< (int) sizeof(numChannels); ++i) {
    printf("%02x", (unsigned int) *tempChar++);
}
printf("\n");
// returned 0000000000000000 so I think its a bug.

//mysql.h  typedef for my_ulonglong and function mysql_num_rows()

#ifndef _global_h
#if defined(NO_CLIENT_LONG_LONG)
typedef unsigned long my_ulonglong;
#elif defined (__WIN__)
typedef unsigned __int64 my_ulonglong;
#else
typedef unsigned long long my_ulonglong;
#endif
#endif

my_ulonglong STDCALL mysql_num_rows(MYSQL_RES *res);
```

`