# ajax post inside on click button

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the following code to verify email:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //global vars
    var emailok = false;
    var form = $("#connexion");

    $("#go").click(function () {
        //okkk
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "email=nedal.jed@gmail.com",
            url: "check_con.php",
            beforeSend: function () {

            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);

            }
        });        
    });
```

and check_con.php is the following

```
<?php
    //data connection file
    //require "config.php";
    require "connexion.php";
    extract($_REQUEST);

    $sql = "select * from Compte where email='$email'";
    $rsd = mysql_query($sql);
    $msg = mysql_num_rows($rsd); //returns 0 if not already exist
    echo $msg;
?>
```

The problem is I don't get any alert to display data, and its not working. What is the problem?

Comment: data: "email=nedal.jed@gmail.com",  shouldn't it  be data: {"email:nedal.jed@gmail.com"}

Comment: @Satya yes, but can be also query.

Comment: What happens if you replace the line in `check_con.php` to read `extract($_REQUEST); return $email;`? You should see the email in the browser alert; otherwise, the problem is possibly inside `connexion.php`.

Comment: what do you get if you add `var_dump($_POST); exit;` at the very begining of your file `check_con.php` ? What does the console says ? Check out the network panel: do you have a 404 ? does the data is sent correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

Similar question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1218562/663604

---

Try this query, instead:

```
$sql = "select COUNT(*) AS `Num` from Compte where email='$email'";
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
echo $rsd[0]["Num"];
```

Please note that `mysql_*` functions are really deprecated. Please use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use
$rsd = mysql_query($sql) or die("error: ".mysql_error());
to see the problem with mysql query.

Comment: There isn't a problem with his query, unless his table or database doesn't exist. So, `mysql_error()` isn't likely to return anything.

Comment: So, if database or table doesn't exist - mysql_error() will print message like "Table 'table_name' doesn't exist".

Comment: True, and good point. However, I was just mentioning that I doubt the OP either completely misspelled his table name or is trying to reference a table that wasn't created. But, it could be helpful to use `mysql_error()`, for sure.